# How do I change an "For all sprite" variable in a "When I start as a clone" hat block?

Tags: mit-scratch

In the game I am programming, I added code that allowed me to tell a specific clone's X pos via a variable for all sprites. This way, I could tell another sprite where to move to. But the X pos variable stayed at 0.

I expected it the variable to be set at the clone's X.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question in the title: "It just works".

Please see my demo at https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/890097874

If you mean something else, please clarify.